# What's the purpose of $\mathsf M\text-\mathsf P$-expressions?

Tags: set-theory, ordinal-analysis

In ordinal notations such as Stegert's ([Ordinal Proof Theory of Kripke–Platek Set Theory Augmented by Strong Reflection Principles](https://repositorium.uni-muenster.de/document/miami/429ac0b8-092f-426d-bf84-1e3a0adc8957/diss_stegert.pdf)) and Rathjen's ([An Ordinal Analysis of parameter free $\Pi_2^1$-Comprehension](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/pime.pdf),) the reflection/projection instances utilize expressions of the form $\mathsf{M}_{\mathbb{M}}^{< \xi}\text-\mathsf{P}_m$ (or something similar) and I have heard them colloquially called "$\mathsf M\text-\mathsf P$-expressions". They seem interesting and powerful, yet I do not understand their purpose: all I managed to tell is that, in Stegert's notation, the $m$ in $\mathsf{P}_m$ corresponds to the "degree of $\Pi^1_m$-indescribable on" but I can't tell much more. Could anyone help?